# insert statement post page to itself issue

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to submit the page to itself but some reason the following code is not working. Also How can I get the table1 primary key ID back after inserting the data successfully? I have a child table which needs this ID. Thanks for any suggestions.

```
<?php
include('db_login.php');
$connection = mysql_connect( $db_host, $db_username, $db_password );

if (!$connection){
  die ("Could not connect to the database: <br />". mysql_error());
}
// Select the database
$db_select=mysql_select_db($db_database);
if (!$db_select){
  die ("Could not select the database: <br />". mysql_error());

  if ($_POST['Submit']) 
  { 
    $first = $_POST["first"];
    $first = mysql_real_escape_string(get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($first): $first);
    $last = $_POST["last"];
    $last = mysql_real_escape_string(get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($last): $last);


    $insertsql = "INSERT INTO table1(FirstName,LastName) VALUES ('".$first."', '" .$last. "')";

    $result1 = mysql_query($insertsql) or die(mysql_error());
 }
 ?>
 <form name="hotlineForm" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>"
  method="post">
 <input id="first" type="text">
 <input id="last" type="text">
 <input type="submit" value="Submit"></form></body>
```

Comment: Describe "not working". Do you get an error message?  Also, `mysql_insert_id()` will get you the newly inserted id from your previous query.

Comment: `get_magic_quotes` is broken (and has been for years). Don't use it and don't rely on it.

Comment: Your form inputs have no `name` attributes.

Comment: I don't get any error message. I am not sure how to debug the code. I am using the remote server for the development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your form inputs to include name attributes.  Without them, your `$_POST` will be empty.

```
<input name='first' id="first" type="text">
<input name='last' id="last" type="text">
<input name='Submit' type="submit" value="Submit">
```

As mentioned in the comments, `get_magic_quotes` should not be used.  You've correctly called `mysql_real_escape_string()` on your inputs already.

Following your insert, get the id from `mysql_insert_id()`:

```
$result1 = mysql_query($insertsql) or die(mysql_error());
$new_id = myqsl_insert_id();
```

Comment: better is to use `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')`, which completely removes the need for field detection, and is 100% reliable.

Answer (score 1):

What part isn't working on the post back? Are you not entering your if statement?

To get the ID of the last insert use the following after your $result1 = mysql_query(...):

```
$primary_id = mysql_insert_id()
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($_POST['Submit'])
```

I don't see a form element with this name.

try:

```
if (isset($_POST['first']) && isset($_POST['last']))
```

For getting inserted ID you can use:

```
mysql_insert_id();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing `}` here:

```
if (!$db_select){
  die ("Could not select the database: <br />". mysql_error());
}  <<----  Close your if statement here.
if ($_POST['Submit'])
```

Currently the code that does the actual work only gets called if the DB **cannot** be selected.
Not very useful.

This is why proper indentation is important.
If you are religious about your indentation, you will spot these kind of errors instantly.

Answer (score 0):

Use a name for the input field and check if it was sents not the `submit`